# Dynamically insert list and items. Items should be draggable from one list to another. Also sort them with sequence number after dragging

Tags: angularjs

```js
var myapp = angular.module('sortableApp', ['ui.sortable']);

myapp.controller('sortableController', function($scope) {

  var tmpList = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    tmpList.push({
      text: 'Item ' + i,
      value: i
    });
  }

  $scope.list = tmpList;
  $scope.sortingLog = [];
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i) {
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Update: ' + logEntry);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      // this callback has the changed model
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i) {
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Stop: ' + logEntry);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 10px 0 30px;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #EA8A8A;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
  cursor: move;
}
.well {
  cursor: move;
}
/***  Extra ***/

body {
  font-family: Verdana, 'Trebuchet ms', Tahoma;
}
.logList {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.logList:before {
  content: 'log';
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.1em;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.nestedDemo ul[dnd-list],
.nestedDemo ul[dnd-list] > li {
  position: relative;
}
.nestedDemo .dropzone ul[dnd-list] {
  min-height: 42px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.nestedDemo .dropzone li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/master/src/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sortableApp">
  <div ng-controller="sortableController" class="container">
    <h2>ui.sortable demo</h2>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="span4">
        <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">
          <div ng-repeat="item in list" class="well">
            {{item.text}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft" style="margin-left: 20px;">
      <ul class="list logList">
        <li ng-repeat="entry in sortingLog track by $index">
          {{entry}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dynamically insert items on this list and it should be able to add list dynamically. List and items should be added on button click event. On each button click, a pop up should arise and ask for corresponding item/list name. List cannot be dragged into an item. They can only be draged above or below existing list. [view of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1buPe.png)

List and items should be sorted after each drag as shown in the attached image. In the attached image section stands for list and lecture stands for image.

Comment: someone please find solution as soon as possible.. please

Comment: In the above attached [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1buPe.png) lecture can be dragged from one section to another. sections can be dragged and arranged, but based on their position section and lecture number changes as shown in image.